# Vuetify button colors are not working

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm using webpack to compile my vuejs project and use the vuetify framework but I can't get the colors to work. For example this:

```
<v-btn color="error">Error</v-btn>
```

Does not produce the red error button, instead it's just the white one. I include all the files using this:

main.js

```
import Vuetify from 'vuetify'
Vue.use(Vuetify)
import '../node_modules/vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css'
```

and App.vue

```
<style lang="stylus">
  @require '../node_modules/vuetify/src/stylus/main'
</style>
```

Could someone tell me what I'm forgetting?

Comment: any error in the console? does the button have any styling?

Comment: The button does have styling, it just ignores the `color="error"` part. It's just a default button. There are no errors at all. I'm really confused

Answer (score 0, accepted):

update to `vuetify v0.16.9` to use color

Answer (score 48):

If you do not wrap your app with the v-app like so...

```
<v-app>
  <router-view/>
</v-app>
```

You will get funny behavior. Wrapping the app in that tag fixed it for me. I obviously skipped the entry statement in the quick setup guide tho :D

Comment: THIS TIME 10000000% :) Ugh... I don't want to admit how many hours I wasted scratching my head ‍♂️

Answer (score 9):

To solve this problem use :

```
<v-app>
```

For more information read this article: [**My application does not look correct**](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/frequently-asked-questions#my-application-does-not-look-correct)

https://vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/frequently-asked-questions#my-application-does-not-look-correct

Comment: Hi! There is already an answer with exactly the same solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50866408/10614791 Please do not post duplicate answers

Comment: I wrote helpful urls for more information from official vuetify documentation, perhaps I should have written it the comments, I am sorry , I am new on this community

Comment: No problem, I was just trying to guide you in the right direction.
In your case, where you were just adding a bit of useful information to an already standing answer, the best thing to do is to edit that answer. (Or write a comment as you said if it's not as important)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an older version of vuetify you may have to use a class instead of color. I had the same issue until I updated the version.

```
   <v-btn class="error">Error</v-btn>
```

However, they also have some documentation in regards to stylus:
https://vuetifyjs.com/en/style/colors

> While convenient, the color pack increases the css export size by
>   ~30kb. Some projects may only require the default provided classes
>   that are created at run-time from the Vuetify bootstrap. To disable
>   this feature, you will have to manually import and build the main
>   stylus file. This will require a stylus loader and a .styl file entry.

```
<style lang="stylus">
  $color-pack = false

  @import '~vuetify/src/stylus/main'
</style>
```